# Зачем вызывается метод при создании экземпляра класса?

Tags: java

```
...... 
PersonsExtracter personsExtracter = new PersonsExtracter().invoke(); 
if (personsExtracter.wasError()) { 
    System.out.println("App was stopped"); 
    return;
}
......
```

Вы могли бы в двух словах объяснить зачем нужен метод `invoke()` в конце объекта `new PersonsExtracter().invoke()` или дать ссылку где можно было почитать на эту тему. Погуглив, внятного ответа не нашел или я не правильно задал вопрос в поисковике. Правильно поставленный вопрос - это правильный ответ на него. Честно говоря ещё не встречал такую конструкцию кода чтоб в конце объекта писали метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто происходит вызов метода `invoke()` класса `PersonsExtracter`, в котором что-то делается, возможно какие-то вещи для инициализации чего-либо, конструирования и прочего и возвращается ссылка на данный же объект (скорее всего).

А т.к. метод не статический, то вызвать его можно только, после создания экземпляра, что собственно и происходит.

Думаю здесь банально эмулируется работа конструктора, т.е. вместо метода

```
class PersonsExtracter {
    public PersonsExtracter invoke() {
         // doing smth
        return this;
    }
}
```

вполне можно было сделать конструктор с той же работой

```
class PersonsExtracter {
    PersonsExtracter() {
        // doing smth
    }
}
```

А по какой причине автор решил сделать так, а не иначе - ну можно его спросить.

Comment: public PersonsExtracter invoke() {
        try {
            persons = readPersons();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File was not found " + e.getMessage());
            error = true;
            return this;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Access file error " + e.getMessage());
            error = true;
            return this;
        }
        error = false;
        return this;
    }
}

Comment: @Junior ну вот. в любом случае возвращает ссылку на созданный экземпляр, предварительно сделав какие-то манипуляции прединициализационные. Обычно вроде на это конструктор есть....

Comment: Просто происходит вызов метода invoke() класса PersonsExtracter.

Comment: это я понял спасибо .я не пойму зачем было написано в конце объекта new PersonsExtracter().invoke()  должно вроде бы  так personsExtracter.invoke()

Comment: вот пример.Main L = new Main();
             L.CallMe();

Comment: пример ....Main L = new Main();

 L.CallMe();......

Comment: почему у него .Main L = new Main();CallMe();

 вот этого не могу понять  почему метод пишется сразу за обьектом

Comment: Main L = new Main();CallMe(); не точный пример у автора инициируется обект и тутже выполняются некие действия  с возвратом обекта... Зачем ? Вызвать переопределенные методы из конструктора черевато неприятностями к примеру

Comment: `personsExtracter.invoke()` это если бы метод был бы статический... а так как метод принадлежит экземпляру, то этот экземпляр надо для начала создать... что и делается при помощи `new PersonsExtracter`.... по сути создается некий экземпляр, который невидим, и у этого невидимки вызывается сразу же метод `invoke()` для совершения какой-либо работы перед тем, как объект сможет наконец попасть в переменную....точнее ссылка на объект

Comment: Вместо того, чтобы просто создать объект - создают объект, тут же говорят ему сделать что-то, и если не получилось - возвращают ссылку на этот самый объект. Чтобы потом можно было попытаться вызвать метод invoke() при более подходящих условиях или и не вызывать больше. Конкретно пример: создаём объект пользователя, и чтобы отобразить его ленту друзей - сразу делаем запрос на сервер. Но у пользователя нет друзей. А это не повод не создавать пользователя. В итоге мы его всё же создали, он может кого задружил, и после этого - мы снова вызываем тот же метод. Ну или для "декоратора" удобно.

Comment: Господа спасибо за ответы  первый раз встретил такую конструкцию  по сути создается некий экземпляр, который невидим, и у этого невидимки вызывается сразу же метод invoke()Вот, теперь мое сознание прояснилось. большое спасибо за ответы .))))))

Comment: Инса́йт!!!Тяжело в учении – легко в бою! СПАСИБО.